# Is it efficient to use Arrays in Recursion, when programming functionally in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

If taking a functional approach, is this the most efficient way to do this?

```
@tailrec
def readLine(in: SomeTypeOfBuffer, a: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val char = in.readByte()
    char match{
        case '\n'  => a 
        case other => readLine(in, a :+ other) 
    }

}
```

Since each recursive call makes a new array, another call to memory has to be made to allocate space for another array, and the previous array freed from memory.

Is this just the price of functional programming?

(I'm relatively new to scala and functional, so plz don't crucify me if I've got something horrendously wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DeFuncT said, it is better to use an *(immutable)* **List** since it will not copy data when building. I will just show you how to do that.

I am also going to apply the advice from @QuickSilver.

```
def readLine(in: SomeTypeOfBuffer): List[Byte] = {
  val NewLine: Byte = '\n'.toByte

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(acc: List[Byte]): List[Byte]
    in.readByte() match {
      case NewLine => acc.reverse
      case char    => loop(other :: acc)
    }

  loop(acc = List.empty)
}
```

PS: In common Scala, you never see **Array**. Maybe the new **ArraySeq** or **Vector**.
Plain arrays are usually only used for performance reasons, and usually contained in the scope of a single method.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using internal mutability for efficiency and providing safe immutable API:

```
@tailrec
private def readLineInner(in: DataInputStream, a: ArrayBuffer[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val char = in.readByte()
    char match{
      case '\n'  => a.toArray
      case other => {
        a.addOne(other)
        readLineInner(in, a )
      }
    }
}

def readLine(in: DataInputStream): Array[Byte] =
  readLineInner(in, new ArrayBuffer[Byte]())
```

Answer (score -2):

Its better to use `List` in your situation, as `List` internally is basically a Linked List, and prepending in a Linked List is O(1)

Edit: updated to prepend

Comment: Prepending is O(1).

Comment: (depending on the implementation of the linked list), but I was more concerned about isn't it bad practice to use mutable objects when you can avoid them in scala?